# Nifti file into 4D-Tensor for C++

Tags: c++, imaging, nifti

I am looking for a function that passing a 4D-Nifti file as an arg or filename, will churn out a 4D Tensor.

Can you point me in a good direction or good library?

1)maybe you can add a concrete example for the answer from the post in [VTK - How to read Tensors/Matrix per cell from a NIFTI Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32137726/vtk-how-to-read-tensors-matrix-per-cell-from-a-nifti-image)

i.e. taking "example.nii" and giving a 4D tensor.

**Attempt**

From other stack-posts and googling, I came across VTK, CImg , Niftilib. But I find it very hard to understand their documentation because it seems to be so basic that people don't even need to comment about it.

For example, I think the VTK Image data might be helpful
http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkImageData.html

but I can't parse through it yet.

I am also curious how easy it is to convert it without any extensive libraries: the Matlab code for that seems very short, so I will continue trying to translate it to C++.

Thank you

The context is DTI 4D imaging of the brain. Converting slices of brain nifti file into a 4D attenuation tensor.

Answer (score 0):

You might might want to look at [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RNifti/readme/README.html) c++ access to nifti images.

I personally love working with the python package Nibabel, which might also be a bit more readable than the matlab implementation, if ou want to translate it yourself.